# I have an array stored as a const, but I get an error that my const is not iterable. Why is my list not iterable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, puppet

I am using puppeteer and trying to get a screenshot of each screen as I loop through with a view for each device, but it is saying the const that I save my list under is not iterable. Exact error: `TypeError: testedMobileDevices is not iterable` I don't understand why the javascript can't iterate through this list to produce a screenshot of each page, from each device in the list.

Here is my script:

```
//import devices from './puppeteerDevices'
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices = puppeteer.devices;
const testedMobileDevices = devices["Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 3 landscape", "Galaxy Note II", "Galaxy Note II landscape",
    "Galaxy S III", "Galaxy S III landscape", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy S5 landscape", "iPad", "iPad landscape",
    "iPad Mini", "iPad Mini landscape", "iPad Pro", "iPad Pro landscape", "iPhone 4", "iPhone 4 landscape",
    "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5 landscape", "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6 landscape", "iPhone 6 Plus", "iPhone 6 Plus landscape",
    "iPhone 7", "iPhone 7 landscape", "iPhone 7 Plus", "iPhone 7 Plus landscape", "iPhone 8", "iPhone 8 landscape",
    "iPhone 8 Plus", "iPhone 8 Plus landscape", "iPhone SE", "iPhone SE landscape", "iPhone X",
    "iPhone X landscape", "iPhone XR", "iPhone XR landscape", "iPhone 11", "iPhone 11 landscape", "iPhone 11 Pro",
    "iPhone 11 Pro landscape", "iPhone 11 Pro Max", "iPhone 11 Pro Max landscape", "Nexus 10", "Nexus 10 landscape",
    "Nexus 4", "Nexus 4 landscape", "Nexus 5", "Nexus 5 landscape", "Nexus 5X", "Nexus 5X landscape", "Nexus 6",
    "Nexus 6 landscape", "Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P landscape", "Nexus 7", "Nexus 7 landscape", "Pixel 2",
    "Pixel 2 landscape", "Pixel 2 XL", "Pixel 2 XL landscape"
];



async function login() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const username = '-------'
    const password = '------'
    const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(`${base_url}/login`);
    //await page.type('[name=username]', username);
    //await page.type('[name=password]', password);
    await page.type('#username', username);
    await page.type('#password', password);
    await page.click('[type=submit]');
    await page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    });
}

async function test() {
    for (let device of testedMobileDevices) {
        await login();
        const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
        const urls = ['feed/', 'project/', 'mynetwork/']
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.emulate(device);

        for (let url of urls) {
            await page.goto(`${ base_url }/${url}`);
            await page.screenshot({
                path: "./screenshot.jpg",
                type: "jpeg",
                fullPage: true
            });
            await page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    });
        }
    }
}

test().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: `const testedMobileDevices = devices["Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 3 landscape", ` does not make any sense. You're invoking the comma operator to access the last value in the list on the `devices` object.

Answer (score 3):

You are not declaring your array correctly.

```js
const testedMobileDevices = ["Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 3 landscape", "Galaxy Note II", "Galaxy Note II landscape", "Galaxy S III", "Galaxy S III landscape", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy S5 landscape", "iPad", "iPad landscape", "iPad Mini", "iPad Mini landscape", "iPad Pro", "iPad Pro landscape", "iPhone 4", "iPhone 4 landscape", "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5 landscape", "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6 landscape", "iPhone 6 Plus", "iPhone 6 Plus landscape",
    "iPhone 7", "iPhone 7 landscape", "iPhone 7 Plus", "iPhone 7 Plus landscape", "iPhone 8", "iPhone 8 landscape",
    "iPhone 8 Plus", "iPhone 8 Plus landscape", "iPhone SE", "iPhone SE landscape", "iPhone X",
    "iPhone X landscape", "iPhone XR", "iPhone XR landscape", "iPhone 11", "iPhone 11 landscape", "iPhone 11 Pro",
    "iPhone 11 Pro landscape", "iPhone 11 Pro Max", "iPhone 11 Pro Max landscape", "Nexus 10", "Nexus 10 landscape",
    "Nexus 4", "Nexus 4 landscape", "Nexus 5", "Nexus 5 landscape", "Nexus 5X", "Nexus 5X landscape", "Nexus 6",
    "Nexus 6 landscape", "Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P landscape", "Nexus 7", "Nexus 7 landscape", "Pixel 2",
    "Pixel 2 landscape", "Pixel 2 XL", "Pixel 2 XL landscape"
];

for (let device of testedMobileDevices) {
  console.log(device)
}
```